# How to backup a Solr database?

Tags: solr

I wonder how to backup (dump) a Solr database?

If it is only to copy some files, then please specify which files (filename, location etc).

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically, the index is stored in `$SOLR_HOME/data`.

Back up that entire folder.

Comment: If an IndexWriter is open while copying that directory, the backup will be corrupted.

Answer (score 12):

We use [Solr Replication](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication) to do our backup.

You can either have a slave that is dedicated to be a backup or use the "backup" command to make a backup on the master (I never used that last method).

Comment: This is the right answer, but I'm amazed how many people are still convinced they need to start/stop Solr or pause their indexing jobs.

Answer (score 0):

In Solr 8/9 version solr backup and restore is available via its replication handler.

It will create a snapshot of the data which you can also restore later.

Here in the solr documentation page you can find more useful information:

https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/making-and-restoring-backups.html#standalone-mode-backups

So this can be used with new 8/9 version if someone is looking for it.