# Dump all documents of Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any way to create a dump file that contains all the data of an index among with its settings and mappings?

A Similar way as mongoDB does with [mongodump](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) 
or as in Solr [its data folder is copied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591258/how-to-backup-a-solr-database-to-a-file) to a backup location.

Cheers!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Here's a new tool we've been working on for exactly this purpose https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump.  You can export indices into/out of JSON files, or from one cluster to another.

Comment: I tried this. While the index data was 112Mb. Exported data was 3 times around 337MB in json format and it took 40 minutes. I don't know it the index is too large, is it really practical looking at the time it takes. What is its benchmark against the snapshot feature provided by ES out of box.

Comment: @Evan does elasticdump uses scan and scroll feature of ElasticSearch internally?

Comment: you can try setting --limit=10000

Answer (score 32):

Elasticsearch supports a snapshot function out of the box:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html

Comment: While very handy, the snapshot don't really export your data in a useable format (json, csv, etc)

Comment: @Andreas Neumann Can snapshot feature can take a backup of subset of documents in a index. Suppose an index has 1000 docs and i want to backup only 500 documents. I would like to do this because I want to import a set of documents and restore in some other index to do some load testing. I don't require the all docs for my task and index is huge and I don't want to take the snapshot of all the data as it will take a lot of time

Comment: Really don't understand why this is the accepted answer, given that it is nothing to do with the original question (which asked for a way to dump ES documents as json, not for a way to back them up using snapshots).

Answer (score 19):

We can use elasticdump to take the backup and restore it, We can move data from one server/cluster to another server/cluster.

**1. Commands to move one index data from one server/cluster to another using `elasticdump`.**

```
# Copy an index from production to staging with analyzer and mapping:
elasticdump \
  --input=http://production.es.com:9200/my_index \
  --output=http://staging.es.com:9200/my_index \
  --type=analyzer
elasticdump \
  --input=http://production.es.com:9200/my_index \
  --output=http://staging.es.com:9200/my_index \
  --type=mapping
elasticdump \
  --input=http://production.es.com:9200/my_index \
  --output=http://staging.es.com:9200/my_index \
  --type=data
```

**2. Commands to move all indices data from one server/cluster to another using `multielasticdump`.**

*Backup*

```
multielasticdump \
  --direction=dump \
  --match='^.*$' \
  --limit=10000 \
  --input=http://production.es.com:9200 \
  --output=/tmp
```

*Restore*

```
multielasticdump \
  --direction=load \
  --match='^.*$' \
  --limit=10000 \
  --input=/tmp \
  --output=http://staging.es.com:9200
```

***Note:***

- If the --direction is dump, which is the default, --input MUST be a URL for the base location of an ElasticSearch server (i.e. http://localhost:9200) and --output MUST be a directory. Each index that does match will have a data, mapping, and analyzer file created.
- For loading files that you have dumped from multi-elasticsearch, --direction should be set to load, --input MUST be a directory of a multielasticsearch dump and --output MUST be a Elasticsearch server URL.
- The 2nd command will take a backup of `settings`, `mappings`, `template` and `data` itself as JSON files.
- The `--limit` should not be more than `10000` otherwise, it will give an exception.
- Get more details [here](https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump).

Comment: You may need to add `--ignoreChildError=true` to the `multielasticdump` commands. Also, setting the `--limit` lower than 10000 (for example, to 1000) may be necessary to prevent some other types of obscure errors. The latter applies to `elasticdump` command as well.

Comment: For `multielasticdump --direction=load` I had to add `--ignoreType='template'`.

Comment: note that you need a trailing slash after the URL, e.g. `multielasticdump ... --input=http://production.es.com:9200/ ...` instead of just  `multielasticdump ... --input=http://production.es.com:9200 ...`. It fails with some very non-descriptive error otherwise.

Answer (score 15):

For your case **Elasticdump** is the perfect answer.

First, you need to download the mapping and then the index

```sh
# Install the elasticdump 
npm install elasticdump -g

# Dump the mapping 
elasticdump --input=http://<your_es_server_ip>:9200/index --output=es_mapping.json --type=mapping

# Dump the data
elasticdump --input=http://<your_es_server_ip>:9200/index --output=es_index.json --type=data
```

If you want to dump the data on any server I advise you to install esdump through docker. You can get more info from this website [Blog Link](https://blog.ruanbekker.com/blog/2017/11/22/using-elasticdump-to-backup-elasticsearch-indexes-to-json/)

Answer (score 13):

ElasticSearch itself provides a way to create data backup and restoration. The simple command to do it is:

```
CURL -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_snapshot/<backup_folder name>/<backupname>' -d '{
    "indices": "<index_name>",
    "ignore_unavailable": true,
    "include_global_state": false
}'
```

Now, how to create, this folder, how to include this folder path in ElasticSearch configuration, so that it will be available for ElasticSearch, restoration method, is well explained [here](http://jee-appy.blogspot.com/2016/11/elasticsearch-backup-and-restore.html). To see its practical demo surf [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Otl-IcmbiDE).

Answer (score 2):

The data itself is one or more lucene indices, since you can have multiple shards. What you also need to backup is the cluster state, which contains all sorts of information regarding the cluster, the available indices, their mappings, the shards they are composed of etc.

It's all within the `data` directory though, you can just copy it. Its structure is pretty intuitive. Right before copying it's better to disable automatic flush (in order to backup a consistent view of the index and avoiding writes on it while copying files), issue a manual flush, disable allocation as well. Remember to copy the directory from all nodes.

Also, next major version of elasticsearch is going to provide a new snapshot/restore api that will allow you to perform incremental snapshots and restore them too via api. Here is the related github issue: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/3826.

Comment: In fact I've tried this solution and it didn't work for me. I copy the data folder as you said to the new remote installation, I tried to start ES but it died due to exceptions. Unfortunately I don't have the log to paste it. Did your solution succeed?

Comment: Yes that's how you should do it. Did you try to restore the index to the same elasticsearch version? Similar machine? Was it a big index? Single node?

Comment: It was a single node, 5 shards, a small index (~2k documents) but different machine. The version was the same (0.9)

Answer (score 2):

You can also dump elasticsearch data in JSON format by http request:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html
`CURL -XPOST 'https://ES/INDEX/_search?scroll=10m'`
`CURL -XPOST 'https://ES/_search/scroll' -d '{"scroll": "10m", "scroll_id": "ID"}'`

Answer (score 2):

At the time of writing this answer(2021), the official way of backing up an ElasticSearch cluster is to snapshot it. Refer to: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshot-restore.html

Comment: Thank you for this! I've updated the question with your answer as the right one, since it's the latest right way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

To export all documents from ElasticSearch into JSON, you can use the esbackupexporter tool. It works with index snapshots. It takes the container with snapshots (S3, Azure blob or file directory) as the input and outputs one or several zipped JSON files per index per day. It is quite handy when exporting your historical snapshots. To export your hot index data, you may need to make the snapshot first (see the answers above).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to massage the data on its way out of Elasticsearch, you might want to use Logstash. It has a handy [Elasticsearch Input Plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html).

And then you can export to anything, from a CSV file to [reindexing the data on another Elasticsearch cluster](https://sematext.com/blog/recipe-reindexing-elasticsearch-documents-with-logstash/). Though for the latter you also have the [Elasticsearch's own Reindex](https://sematext.com/blog/reindexing-data-with-elasticsearch/).