# Transfer data from Redshift to Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-redshift, data-transfer

I have some GB of data to be transferred to ES. I know of a way to first dump data from Redshift to S3 and then to ES.

Is there any other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [Elastic Dump](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticdump)

For reference: [how to move elasticsearch data from one server to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547560/how-to-move-elasticsearch-data-from-one-server-to-another)