# How to resolve indent error in elasticdump api while migrating data from one elasticsearch server to another?

Tags: elasticsearch, npm

While following the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35705575/10060068) on how to migrate data from one elasticsearch server to another, I ran the command for copying the mapping and got this error:

```
sudo elasticdump --input=localhost:9200/e0399e012222b9fe70ec7949d1cc354f17369f20 --output=A.B.C.D:9200/e0399e012222b9fe70ec7949d1cc354f17369f20 --type=mapping                                   
Wed, 12 Dec 2018 07:01:31 GMT | starting dump
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'localhost:9200/e0399e012222b9fe70ec7949d1cc354f17369f20'
    at Error (native)
```

How can I resolve this issue or is there any other better way of achieving the same?

Comment: you should probably prefix your URLs with `http://` otherwise elasticdump might think it's dealing with a file

Comment: Yes, that is great. However, I faced another issue:
`Error Emitted => {"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Limit of total fields [1000] in index [e0399e012222b9fe70ec7949d1cc354f17369f20] has been exceeded"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Limit of total fields [1000] in index [e0399e012222b9fe70ec7949d1cc354f17369f20] has been exceeded"}`
@Val

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to prefix your URLs with `http://` otherwise elasticdump things it's dealing with a file.

```
sudo elasticdump --input=http://localhost:9200/e0399e012222b9fe70ec7949d1cc354f17369f20 --output=http://35.200.253.43:9200/e0399e012222b9fe70ec7949d1cc354f17369f20 --type=mapping  
                           ^
                           |
                       add this (also for output -->)
```

Then the second error you're getting has to do with the fact that you have more than 1000 fields in your source index. You can get around this by changing the settings in your destination index by running this before you run elasticdump:

```
curl -XPUT -H 'Content-type: application/json' http://35.200.253.43:9200/e0399e012222b9fe70ec7949d1cc354f17369f20/_settings -d '{
  "index" : {
    "mapping" : {
      "total_fields" : {
        "limit" : "2000"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: I changed the setttings to 10k with a message received: acknowledged:true. Even then, I am getting the same error.

Comment: And I am running the command to migrate the mapping
`> $ sudo elasticdump --input=http://127.0.0.1:9200/e0399e012222b9fe70ec7949d1cc354f17369f20 --output=http://A.B.CD:9200/e0399e012222b9fe70ec7949d1cc354f17369f20 --type=mapping`

Comment: Can you wipe the destination index clean, recreate it, run the curl I gave you and try elasticdump again, please?

Comment: I just entered the dest server and found out that there exists no such index for me to wipe out.