# Migrate Elasticsearch from local machine to online server

Tags: elasticsearch, webserver

I have been working on Elasticsearch. I want to migrate my Elasticsearch data to online server. I am using Elasticsearch 7.6 on my local machine (Windows operating System) with the web application. Now i want to move this to online Web server. Is there any tool to do it. In MySql we create dump files. How to do it in Elasticsearch.

i know this is not coding question but i want to explore the answers as my research didn't get me anything.

The online web server is Linux based on a shared hosting.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to move elasticsearch data from one server to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547560/how-to-move-elasticsearch-data-from-one-server-to-another)

Comment: I already went through it. But i was not sure about from local machine which is windows. But i will definitely take guide from it

Comment: The machine OS/vendor does not matter. If an instance has an accessible URL (localhost or live), the above should work.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a snapshot of the local elastic indexes, Install the same version of elasticsearch on the online server and then restore the snapshot there. 
Read more on this here : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshot-restore.html
and here 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshots-restore-snapshot.html

Comment: Thank you i will definitely take a look