# Compare data between Elastic Search and RDS

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, amazon-rds

We are moving our data from RDS to elastic search and the data volume is around 80GB with around 90 million records.

We have been using bulk api of elastic search for indexing the data but we want to take an entire dump of elastic records and compare the records with our RDS as we want to make sure that the data from RDS is moved correctly to Elastic. In Elastic, we have been combining multiple tables of RDS into a single elastic index, is there any way to take the dump of elastic index into a document or into multiple files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dump all documents of Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243074/dump-all-documents-of-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 0):

There's no solution out of the box but there's an old post from the elastic website which explain some solutions:

https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-verifying-data-integrity-with-external-data-stores

Hope it help.